# Sharing the Master Keys in BIP32

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, multi-signature, bip32-hd-wallets

What is the Best way to share the `Master Public Key` and `Master Chain code` generated using `BIP32` in `Bicoins` with a user that I don't trust ?

I just want the second user to monitor my wallet and not spend coins. What will be the best way to share my `Master Keys` ?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the wallet (keypath) you are using.

If your wallet is based on BIP44 (most wallets are), sharing the **extended master public key** will not allow the other party deriving pubkeys to monitor incoming funds (because of hardened key derivation). You need to share the specific **account extended public key**. Your fist account is at keypath `m / 44' / 0' / 0'`, second at `m / 44' / 0' / 1'`, etc.

Instead of sharing the pure pubkey together with the chaincode, we use "extended public keys". You can identify a such base58check encoded string by the first 4 chars "xpub".

As far as I know there are only a few wallets in the wilde who can do such exports/imports.